# What is this beast in Thor: Love and Thunder trailer?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, thor-love-and-thunder

In the newly released *Thor: Love and Thunder* trailer we see a large beast. What is this beast?

[image: A still frame from the trailer, in which we see Thor and Korg standing on a rock, in front of what seems to be the corpse of a gigantic beast.]

Comment: Relevant meta question if you're consdering voting to close as future work: [When are questions about characters in trailers Future Works?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13657/when-are-questions-about-characters-in-trailers-future-works)

Comment: possibly bigger question, but is that _Thanos_ next to him? Whoever it is is bigger than Thor, and seems to have a guantletted left hand

Comment: Korg is next to Thor in this picture

Comment: @Clockwork Indeed, the trailer has already been released, so it is not a 'future work'.

Comment: @Tristan I hate to break it to you, but it's probably just Korg.  From Ragnarok.   Could not speculate on whether Korg has the Infinity Gauntlet.  Seems to have two gauntlets... two Infinity Gauntlets?  Why not.

Comment: that makes so much more sense. I was thinking Thanos would be ridiculous. I agree he seems to have two gauntlets, it was mostly just the fact the left looks a lot bigger, but that could just be the angle I guess. Or maybe it is just a bigger gauntlet

Comment: @Tristan Could be the version of Thanos from that one episode of *What If?* where T'chala was Starlord instead of Peter Quill, and he was just so darned likeable that even Thanos was cool and friendly with him.  I somehow doubt we'll be seeing that version in the main films though.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

According to [this link talking about easter eggs](https://www.newsweek.com/thor-love-thunder-trailer-easter-eggs-explained-1698837) in the new trailer, that would be [Falligar the Behemoth](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Falligar_(Earth-616)).

A similar view can be seen; apparently from [Thor: God of Thunder Vol 1 3](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor:_God_of_Thunder_Vol_1_3):

[image: Thor is standing on a rock, looking at a gigantic, apparently dead, beast. Thor is commenting how he knew that god, calling him Falligar the Behemoth.]

Comment: Wow that's a close match in frame composition.

Comment: @tbrookside Only significant difference being he's by himself in this version.

Comment: The beast in the comic has a third spike on its tail. Must be a different species. :)

Comment: Cue 27 million words of internet argument.

Comment: @Barmar I think that's an arm, and those are claws.  The 3rd one might be there in the original image, it's just too dark and foggy to see in that shot.

Answer (score 1):

According to the (now-released) film, that would be

> **Falligar, God of the Falligarians**, one of the nicest gods you'll ever meet.
>
> [image]

Comment: Interesting, so he doesn't have exactly the same title.

Comment: @Clockwork - The director refers to this as Planet Falligar in the commentary